# this.state within react-navigation screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having trouble accessing and defining state. My app uses react-navigation. Overall within my app I can always work with state (without errors), but within the primary tabbar screens, I get a "null is not an object" error when I use a simple definition of state like I do below.

I am not using redux

```js
export class Review_Screen extends React.Component {

  // set title at the top of the page
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    this.state = {
      // general ID info
      barcode: params.productdata.barcode,
      userID: params.user.ID,
      username: params.user.name,
      expanded: false,
      testing: 'hallo hallo',
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log('-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-');
    console.log(this.state.testing);
    console.log('-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-');
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    
etc...

// results in error "null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.testing')
```

I assume this is because I am supposed to work differently with state when I am within react-navigation.

How do I define some local state variables? What is best practice? I will at some point go to redux, but am not ready for that yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's embarrassing. The issue arose because I had my react-native on "hot reloading", while I was coding.

This basically means that I was asking for a variable that wasn't defined, because the constructor wasn't called (the app was live while coding).

Once I restart or reload the app, then it does define the state (because while initially loading the app it calls the constructor().

Hope this serves someone else..